# what does Percentage symbol (%) in the IAM policy mean

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

when I use firehose and enable logging it automatically generate the following lines for IAM policy:

```
            Statement:
          - Sid: ''
            Effect: Allow
            Action:
            - s3:AbortMultipartUpload
            - s3:GetBucketLocation
            - s3:GetObject
            - s3:ListBucket
            - s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads
            - s3:PutObject
            Resource:
            - arn:aws:s3:::%FIREHOSE_BUCKET_NAME%
            - arn:aws:s3:::%FIREHOSE_BUCKET_NAME%/*
```

What I cannot understand is what % means in the above? I mean this%FIREHOSE_BUCKET_NAME%. Can anyone explain it?

Comment: `%FIREHOSE_BUCKET_NAME%` means it's a variable name: Firehose will replace that with the bucket name you specify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation, these lines can be removed.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/create-configure.html

Comment: ...to be complete, nt have read the question, ... I have one question you should answer by modifying your answer .... "which lines" are you talking about? And using referral is fine..but shortly explain to what you are referring. Links have expiration dates set by webmasters, clients or wordpress execution style!

Comment: AWS has quietly updated their documentation and this weird string is no longer mentioned in their docs. But it looks like a placeholder value that their console used to insert and, yes, it was meant to be replaced or removed. ([Here](https://pdf4pro.com/cdn/amazon-kinesis-data-firehose-3389f9.pdf) is an old, non-AWS-hosted version of the doc that mentions it, for context.) Wow, what a really poor choice for a placeholder value. It sure looks like a variable.